# Mead left for years; is it still good?

Tags: mead

I made a 5 gallon batch of mead, I racked it once and then left it in my carboy for a number of years, during which the vapor lock water evaporated. Is it still OK to try? Or should I toss it? Looks clear and smells good. So basically initial fermentation was done.

Comment: Have you tried tasting it yet? That's your best option :-)

Comment: From a health perspective, we would expect it to be safe to drink. Please give it a try, come back, and post an answer to your question. That way we, and anyone else that is wondering the same thing, will know.